# Sci-fi novel, probably from the 50's about a former soldier abducted by aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a sci-fi novel about 13 years ago. Been trying to find it again for a long time now.

It's about a former soldier (SAS?), who gets abducted from his home by giant aliens in the middle of the night. He is taken aboard a UFO, together with two(?) other individuals, one female and one male. Highly intelligent flying bug-like aliens are in charge of the operation.
In the end the protagonist steals a spaceship and crash lands back on earth, in the Thames river, London.

I know that the author was British, and that he was very productive. The story was probably written in the 50's or 60's.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  What about the story suggests a 1950s time frame?  What happens to the other abductees?

Comment: Are there 2 Alien groups? Or are the "giant aliens" the same as the "Highly intelligent flying bug-like aliens" If there are 2 groups, are the 2 working together or on opposite sides?

Comment: Thank you! 1950's time frame is purely based on my memory of the book. It had that distinct 50s cover art. I remember looking up the author when I still had the book, and I'm pretty positive he was active in the 50s-60s.

I don't remember that much act two. I just have vague memories. I want to say that they were captive on a desolate desert planet. Why, I don't remember.
I don't remember what happens to the other abductees, but I do remember there was a love-triangle drama between the three.

Comment: There are two alien groups. The giants are of low intelligence and are under the leadership of the bugs.

Comment: _British_ and _very productive_ makes me think of Lionel Fanthorpe. He was a master of the quantity beats quality approach to writing. The timing is plausible as well.

Comment: [Fanthorpe's bibliography is here](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?2161) in case any of the titles ring a bell. He wrote hundreds of books so I feel disinclined to check every book on the list.